# Is this type of proof by induction correct in Sylow's Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction, proof-explanation

The following is the first part of the Sylow's Thm:

[image]

My question is: if order of $G$ was $p^a$ (and not $p^am$) then we could start with $|G|=1$ which means $a=0$. Then supposed that the theorem holds for all $a$'s up to $p-1$ then proved for $p$. But the problem here is that statement by induction involved more than one parameter, i.e. not only $p^a$ but also $m$. Why $m$ is absolutely irrelevant? Or otherwise why we don't go another induction on $m$, since **especially** when we say $|G|=1$ we don't mean arbitrary $m$ and we consider $m=1$ the smallest number in induction?

**Added**: in the 2nd paragraph of the proof it says "If we let P be a subgroup of G containing N such that ..."; How we know that such P definitely exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induction is only on the size of the group $G$. So the induction hypothesis is that for *any* group $H$ of order less than $|G|$, if $|H|=p^\alpha m$ for *any* prime $p$, *any* $\alpha$, and *any* $m$ not divisible by $p$ (so long as $p^\alpha m<|G|$), $\text{Syl}_p(G) \neq \emptyset$.

Thus the base case is $|G|=1$, in which case there are no primes dividing $|G|$ and there is nothing to show.

Comment: Why the base case must not be $|G|=p$? Yes, the induction is on $|G|$ but *induction* starts when $|G|=p$.

Comment: Also, as I understand from your answer induction's hypothesis assumes $\text{Syl}_p(G) \neq \emptyset$ for all $G$'s with $|G|=1, \dots, p^am-1$; then text tries to prove for $|G|=p^am$ and anytime in the process of reducing order the new order falls between $1, \dots, p^am-1$. Am I understanding correctly? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to state the theorem is as follows: if $G$ is a group, then for any prime $p$ dividing $|G|$, $\text{Syl}_p(G) \neq \emptyset$. The theorem is not proved for _fixed_ $p$ but rather _any_ $p$. So if we induct on $|G|$, we have to start with the smallest possible group, $|G|=1$. Now we assume for all $G$ with $|G| < n$, for any $p$ dividing $|G|$ $\text{Syl}_p(G) \neq \emptyset$. Then the result is shown for $|G|=n$. In order to do that, you need to first write $|G|=n=p^\alpha m$ for some prime $p$ dividing $n$ and some $m$ not divisible by $p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is also a line in the proof that I don't understand (the existence of $P$ - the "**Added**" part in the OP). I'd appreciate it if you please help me about that also. Thank you.

Comment: A subgroup $\overline{P}$ of $G/N$ must be of the form $P/N$ for some $P \leq G$ such that $P$ contains $N$. Let $P=\{g \in G : gN \in \overline{P}\}$. $P \leq G$ because if $g,h \in P$, $gN, hN \in \overline{P}$. Hence $(gN)(hN)^{-1}=(gh^{-1})N \in \overline{P}$, so $gh^{-1} \in P$. Moreover $N \leq P$ because if $n \in N$, $nN=N \in \overline{P}$. Finally, $\overline{P}=P/N$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the author uses induction on $|G|$ and not induction on $a$. In addition if we assume that $G$ is of order equal to $p^a$ for some prime number $p$ then there is nothing to prove because the theorem holds by assumption($G$ is the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$.)

0

Comment: Why the base case must not be $|G|=p$? Yes, the induction is on $|G|$ but *induction* starts when $|G|=p$.

Comment: ok, fair question!. It is bassically the same thing. Assuming that $p$ is a prime and starting the base case for $|G|=p$,if you can prove the statement for every group of order $p^am$ then u have proved the theorem. Because the same proof holds for any other prime number(case $|G|=1 does not really matter).